# Jackson CSV missing columns

Tags: java, parsing, csv, jackson

I'm using [Jackson CSV](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv) to parse a CSV file into POJOs.  My issue is that if a row in the CSV has too few columns, the parser doesn't complain and just sets the rest of the fields to null.

Parsing code:

```
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    csvMapper.addMixInAnnotations(Person.class, PersonCsvMixin.class);
    CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(Person.class).withHeader();
    MappingIterator<Person> it = csvMapper.reader(dataClass).with(schema).readValues(csv);
    LinkedList<Person> output = new LinkedList<>();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        output.push(it.next());
    }
```

Mixin:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

@JsonPropertyOrder(value = { "FirstName", "LastName", "Title"})
public abstract class Person {
    @JsonProperty("LastName")
    public abstract String getLastName();
    @JsonProperty("FirstName")
    public abstract String getFirstName();
    @JsonProperty("Title")
    public abstract String getTitle();
}
```

Data class:

```
public class OfficespaceInputEmployee implements Serializable{
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String title;
    // .. getters and setters
}
```

If I parse a file like the following, no errors occur even though the middle record is missing two fields. Instead, LastName and Title become `null`

```
"FirstName", "LastName", "Title"
"John", "Smith", "Mr"
"Mary"
"Peter", "Jones", "Dr"
```

Is there a feature to enable that will cause this to error instead?

Comment: Show your MappingIterator usage.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. added MappingIterator usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw an exception yourself when you build the output LinkedList inside 
the while loop:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Person line = it.next();
    //call a method which checks that all values have been set 
    if (thatMethodReturnsTrue){
        output.push(line);
    } else{
      throw SomeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know I could do that, but I was hoping that the library would actually check this at parse-time, as it does when there are too many fields.

Comment: I haven't found any option you can pass to make the parser strict. I think there may not be one

Comment: @rewolf would've been useful to have a CsvParser.Feature that you can enable on the CsvMapper. You can add a suggestion on github

Comment: The CsvMapper's base class ObjectMapper has a configure method which has some useful configurations but i don't think it applies to the csv parser. It would be useful to have for csv parsing a feature similar to this one for deserializaiton: csvMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, false)

Comment: There isn't currently a way to do this in the library, so I will add the check when iterating, and mark this as the answer.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread, but as I run into the same question myself, let me share the solution :

*csvMapper.configure(CsvParser.Feature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_COLUMNS, true);* will do the trick.

Comment: I've got this nice setup:


myObjectReader = csvMapper

              .readerFor(Map.class)

              .with(csvSchema)

              .without(IGNORE_TRAILING_UNMAPPABLE)

              .without(ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA)

              .with(FAIL_ON_MISSING_COLUMNS);

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest filing an RFE for issue tracker, for something like `CsvParser.Feature.REQUIRE_ALL_COLUMNS`: if enabled, parser would throw an exception to indicate that one or more of expected columns are missing.
This sounds like a useful addition to me.

Comment: Created issue on Github https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/issues/113